# Query to Find Best Five Restaurants

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to get the best five restaurants in my database . The structure of the database complicates my linq query .

That's how I work, I have a table "comments" that contains a foreign key to my restaurant and I have three choices for the vote between 1 and 5.

Table example:

```
- idRestaurant
- ratingOne
- ratingTwo
- ratingThree
```

I would therefore classified a restaurant with a average of the average of the three notes

If for example I have some records in the table

```
idRestaurant 1 - RatingOne 2 - RatingTwo 2 - RatingThree - 2

idRestaurant 1 - RatingOne : 4 - RatingTwo : 4 - RatingThree - 4

idRestaurant 2 - RatingOne : 3 - RatingTwo : 3 - RatingThree - 3

idRestaurant 2 - RatingOne : 4 - RatingTwo : 4 - RatingThree - 4

idRestaurant : 3 - RatingOne 1 - RatingTwo 1 - RatingThree - 1

idRestaurant : 3 - RatingOne 1 - RatingTwo 1 - RatingThree - 1

idRestaurant : 4 - RatingOne 1 - RatingTwo 1 - RatingThree - 1

idRestaurant : 4 - RatingOne 1 - RatingTwo 1 - RatingThree - 1

idRestaurant : 4 - RatingOne 1 - RatingTwo 1 - RatingThree - 1

idRestaurant : 4 - RatingOne 5 - RatingTwo 5 - RatingThree - 5
```

I would like the result of my LINQ send me a list of idRestaurants in order of overall score without duplicated restaurant
example :
{ 2,1,4,3 }

I have the following query

```
var restosss = (from w in db.restos_cote 
                group w by w.idRestoSuccursale into g 
                select new 
                {
                   idRestoSuccursale = g.Key, Restos = g 
                });
```

but it also needs to be sorted by average score.

Comment: Please show effort before posting a question.  There are few people on Stack Overflow that want to do your work for you.  Have you tried something?  What is working, what is not working?

Comment: Hello, i aleary have a query for group by resto but i want orber by average of average of three rating...

var restosss = (from w in db.restos_cote group w by w.idRestoSuccursale into g select new { idRestoSuccursale = g.Key, Restos = g  });

Answer (score 0):

Well the average of the three values is just `val1 + val2 + val3 / 3`

Then you can use `Average` on this calculation.

```
var restosss = (from w in db.restos_cote 
                group w by w.idRestoSuccursale into g 
                select new 
                {
                   idRestoSuccursale = g.Key, Restos = g
                   avgRating = g.Average(x => (x.RatingOne + x.RatingTwo + x.RatingThree) / 3.0)
                })
                //if you want "best ratings" first, else use OrderBy
                .OrderByDescending(m => m.avgRating)
                //take only the 5 best ratings
                .Take(5);
```

By the way, if you just want a correct ordering, but don't use the average result, you don't need to divide by 3.0